# How do I dynamically create charts using strings in aesthetics in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, histogram

Please consider the following example

```
ggplot(data = titanic, aes(x = Fare)) + 
  geom_histogram()
```

Here I am creating a histogram with data from titanic dataframe and the x axis is `Fare`. The Fare is not passed as a string. So when I try to loop all the attributes to create multiple graphs say using `names(dataset)`, i get a vector of `strings` and my loop would look something like this

```
for (attr in names(dataset)) {
    ggplot(data = dataset, aes(x = attr)) + 
      geom_histogram()
}
```

Here `attr is a string` in each loop but that is not what ggplot is expecting. In the initial example Fare was not passed as a string(without quotes) and within the for loop, it would have been passed as "Fare".

So I want to know how to dynamically create graphs for all the columns dynamically or what should I convert my string to ("Fare" to Fare)? (i.e. what is this format(Fare without quotes) technically called?)

Comment: With `?aes_string`

Comment: Or `melt` your data and use `facet_wrap` (no loop, single graph)

Comment: @VincentGuillemot, if I try the initial example with `Fare`, I get the histogram but when I run the same with `aes_string("Fare")`, I get the following error `Don't know how to automatically pick scale for object of type uneval. Defaulting to continuous.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created the following example because I can't seem to find the correct `titanic`data-set. In this example I have two variables, x and y (and a simple quadratic model).

```
dat <- data.frame(x=rnorm(100))
dat$y <- - 3 * (dat$x)^2 + 1 + rnorm(100)
```

If I use the regular function `aes`, the following command works just fine.

```
ggplot(data=dat, aes(x=x, y=y)) + 
  geom_point() + geom_smooth()
```

With `aes_string`, you simply need to replace the name of the variables with character strings. Here I put them in a vector.

```
obj <- c("x", "y")
ggplot(data=dat, aes_string(x=obj[1], y=obj[2])) + 
  geom_point() + geom_smooth() +
  theme_bw()
```

I'm working with R version 3.4.4 and `ggplot2_2.2.1.9000`.